# scrapy: Writing unicode in a file writing Pipeline

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, python-unicode

I have a scrapy Pipeline defined that should write any Item Field crawled by a scraper to text. One of the fields contains HTML code. I'm having issues writing it to file due to the notorious Unicode error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 100: ordinal not in range(128)

Scrapy can write out all of the fields as json in the logfile. Could someone explain what needs to be done to handle the character encoding for writing files? Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
import codecs

class SupportPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):        
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            with codecs.open("%s.%s" % (prefix, key), 'wb', 'utf-8') as f:
#            with open("%s.%s" % (prefix, key), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(value.encode('utf-8'))

        return item
```

Comment: can you try with just simple writr, it seems likr double encoding , try just `f.write(value)`

Comment: also not that it should matter, try mentioning `encoding='utf8'` while opening writable file stream